# Perl: integration tests

Tags: perl, testing, integration-testing

I'm asking for best practice.

Usually I put all unit tests into t/, but what about integration tests?

Where are the best place for integration tests?
And how them will be named?

Answer (score 5):

There isn't a globally accepted naming/location convention for integration tests that I am aware of in Perl.

From my observations most people put everything under t/.

Some folk split tests up into sub-directories under t/ (so you might have integration tests in a separate t/integration/ directory).

Some folk use a file-prefix (so you might have integration tests named 'I-whatever.t').

Some folk don't care - and just throw everything into the same directory.

I've occasionally seen folk separate out a group of tests into a separate directory at the same level as 't/' - but that's been usually for tests that are not normally run (e.g. author specific tests for CPAN dists) rather than for integration vs unit).